# C pass array of structs by reference or by value to a function

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a function in C which takes an array of structs as an argument:

```
int load_ini_parms(char * ini_file,
                   struct test_object s[],
                   int num,
                   struct lwm2m_object * l)
```

My question is, would it be better programming practice to pass a pointer to an array of structs? What would be the advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: By using `struct test_object s[]` as argument, the compiler actually sees it as `struct test_object *s`. So you're already passing a pointer (to the first element).

Comment: Passing an array as an argument technically equals passing a pointer to its first element, so if you passed a pointer to an array, you would've simply passed a pointer to a `struct` pointer, which might be sometimes useful but unnecessary here

Comment: Use C99+ and a vla argument.

Comment: @artic sol  Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Beware that VLAs are optionals in C11

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't make any difference because *passing an array as a function argument **decays** into a pointer*.

The function

```
int load_ini_parms(char *ini_file, struct test_object s[], int num, struct lwm2m_object *l)
```

is equivalent to

```
int load_ini_parms(char *ini_file, struct test_object *s, int num, struct lwm2m_object *l)
```

The information regarding to the size of the array is lost in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to what others here say, I say it *does* make a difference as to what may be a "better programming practice":

Declaring the parameter as an array indicates to the user of the function that you expect, well, an *array*.

If you only declare a pointer this does not tell anyone if you expect a single element or possibly multiple.

Hence, I'd prefer the pointer for single-element parameters (e.g. "output" parameters) and the array for (potentially) multiple elements.